# mdl-js-ripple-effect not working on IPad IOS safari 13.1(beta)

Tags: material-design-lite

I am testing an application on Ipad with the iOS safari v 13.1 (beta). All buttons in the application use "mdl-js-ripple-effect" is not working. there are around 1260+ instances and 400+ file using this class.

Comment: I have the same problem and to be more precise: the buttons work only on double tap.

Comment: Same issue here... yes, double tap works but no single tap.

Answer (score 2):

Look here: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/5281

> ... MDL is no longer maintained. Please
>   update your systems as you can to [Material Components for Web](https://material.io/develop/web/).

Comment: Here you will find more information to migrate your application: https://material.io/develop/web/docs/migrating-from-mdl/

Comment: Are you really sure same problem is not happening on MDC Web?

Comment: I've tested MDC demo sites in Safari on iOS 13, e.g. https://material-example-app-shrine.glitch.me/ It works well.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been updated with the solution, update css:

```
.mdl-ripple { background: #000; opacity: 0.001; }
```