# mdl-js-ripple-effect breaks MDL buttons on iOS 13.2 (beta)

Tags: ios, angularjs, material-design-lite

We have a legacy AngularJS webapp that uses the [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io) framework for the UI.

Now a couple of days ago the buttons with `mdl-button` and `mdl-js-ripple-effect` classes suddenly stopped working. Actually now they only work if you make a "double tap" (tapping twice) instead of the usual single tap. After removing the ripple effect, they work again.

Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

- StackOverflow: [mdl-js-ripple-effect not working on IPad IOS safari 13.1(beta)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858598/mdl-js-ripple-effect-not-working-on-ipad-ios-safari-13-1beta)
- Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/5281
- WebKit Bugzilla: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202802